# How to find an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B'$ such that $[T]_{\mathcal B'}$ has a block diagonal form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear operator $T:\mathbb R^3\longrightarrow \mathbb R^3$ whose matrix in the canonical basis is, $$[T]_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}3&1&8\\ 1&3&-8\\ -1&1&2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Let $v=(1, 1, 0)$ be the eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda=4$. Furthermore, suppose $$W=\{\,u\in \mathbb R^3: \langle u, v=(1, 1, 0)\rangle=0\,\},$$ is $T$-invariant. Using these facts how could I show there is an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B'$ for $\mathbb R^3$ such that $$[T]_{\mathcal B'}=\begin{pmatrix} *&0&0\\ 0&*&*\\ 0&*&*\end{pmatrix}?$$

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you already know all these about $T$, then if you choose any orthonormal basis $w_1,w_2$ of $W$ and extend it with (the normed version of) $\,v$, i.e. with $\,w_0:=\displaystyle\frac v{\sqrt2}$, then we will have
$$T(w_0)=4w_0,\quad T(w_1),\,T(w_2)\in W$$
by $v$ being eigenvector and $W$ being invariant.

So the first column of $[T]_{(w_0,w_1,w_2)}$ (i.e. $T(w_0)$ coordinated in $(w_0,w_1,w_2)$) is $\pmatrix{4\\0\\0}$, and the other two columns will omit $w_0$-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

The invariant subspace $W$ being described is the orthogonal complement of $v$. The subspace spanned by the eigenvectors associated with a particular eigenvalue is always invariant. So maybe all you need to do is check that T is not degenerate. If it is not then the matrix representation of the direct sum of $v$ and $W$ will give you the desired form. 
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement